# Native Query Working on MS SQL Server Management Studio but not on Code

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My Query is not working on code but on MS SQL Server Management Studio. My Repository class is below. Also the SQL in its pure form. I have tried putting service_name in square brackets like this [service_name] because it looked like a keyword but that doesn't help. The error is "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'service_name'."

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY service_name ORDER 
BY date_time_inserted) AS row_number FROM MServiceStatus) AS rows WHERE 
row_number = 1

@Repository
public interface ServiceStatusRepository  extends 
JpaRepository<ServiceStatus, 
Integer> {
@Query(value ="SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
service_name ORDER BY date_time_inserted)" +
        " AS row_number FROM MServiceStatus) AS rows WHERE row_number = 1", 
nativeQuery = true)
Page<ServiceStatus> findLatestStatuses(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: Please post the _exact_ code you are actually running.  What you have above will fail, but it will fail because you have an unclosed string literal in the `@Query` annotation.

Comment: That's not what the error is about, I'm not getting errors on the IDE. the code is below.
@Repository
public interface ServiceStatusRepository  extends JpaRepository<ServiceStatus, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY service_name ORDER BY date_time_inserted)
            " AS row_number FROM MServiceStatus) AS rows WHERE row_number =:'1'", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<ServiceStatus> findLatestStatuses(Pageable pageable);
}

Comment: You have sorting in your native query, and it's prohibited in Spring Data JPA. Please check: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_native_queries . `Spring Data JPA does not currently support dynamic sorting for native queries, because it would have to manipulate the actual query declared, which it cannot do reliably for native SQL.`

Comment: *Incorrect syntax near 'service_name'.* is seems like SQL Server error. However query is indeed valid. Have you tried to pass a query as one line?

Comment: @Alexander, I did, that didn't help. I think Ken is right, will have to move the query to a View. Thanks guys.